# On Firebase, why does remove work on push but not on set?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write on Firebase an object with this structure and when a user reloads or leaves page, the user's data will be removed from Firebase.

```
/users {
  1: {name: name, win: win},
  2: {name: name, win: win}
}
```

This code does that but generates random Id each push so I cannot interfere with each user's data later:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var userRef = database.ref("/users");

function createNewUser() {
    var newUser = $('#newUser').val().trim();

    if (newUser) {
        var con = userRef.push({
            name: newUser,
            win: 0,
            loss: 0
        });
        con.onDisconnect().remove();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}

$('#startButton').on('click', createNewUser);
```

This code is similar but has error:

> onDisconnect is not a function

```
function createNewUser() {
    var newUser = $('#newUser').val().trim();

    if (newUser) {
        var con = database.ref('users/ + 1).set({
            name: newUser,
            win: 0,
            loss: 0
        });
        con.onDisconnect().remove();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

If I use push, I can retrieve each user's ID but I still won't be able to change user's data, especially if 1 of the 2 users leaves.

Answer (score 0):

When using `.push`, Firebase will always generate a random key for this new entry.
You can use `.set` instead of `.push` and you'll need to add to the path/ref a unique identifier for each user, like userName or userId as `userRef.child('/userid').set`

Or you can capture the new entry after creation, and get the new generated random key, and then use it for the `.remove`

See [Firebase Documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)

Hope that helps.
All the best.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I've read their documentation before but I'm still stuck.